# Dynamic rows on table c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

two part question:

**1:**

I am using a session state refresh to hold count of the page reloads but when using a series of `if` statements the validation isn't working. Code at the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

**2:**
Using session state against postback doesn't appear to be the most efficient method of doing this, if I added another table with the same functionality, the count would affect both tables.
For example if I only wanted people to be able to add a maximum of three rows to a table, on two tables, they would only be able to add four rows in total.

What would be a better method of storing a count for separate refreshes?

**Update**
I have found the issue with the code not adding rows to the existing but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Basically each iteration is deleting the existing row then adding a single row again. So there will never be more than one row.

Any ideas?

```
namespace FormTest
{
    public partial class About : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            tbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Inset;
            tbl.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["count"] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int count = (int)Session["count"];
            count++;
            Session["count"] = count;
        }
    }

    protected void cmdCreate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        tbl.Controls.Clear();

        int rows = 1;
        int cols = 4;

        if ((int)Session["count"] == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                TableRow rowNew = new TableRow();
                tbl.Controls.Add(rowNew);
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();
                    Label lblNew = new Label();
                    lblNew.Text = "(" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + ")<br />";

                    TextBox tbNew = new TextBox();
                    cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
                    cellNew.Controls.Add(tbNew);

                    rowNew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((int)Session["count"] == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    TableRow rowNew = new TableRow();
                    tbl.Controls.Add(rowNew);
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                    {
                        TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();
                        Label lblNew = new Label();
                        lblNew.Text = "(" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + ")<br />";

                        TextBox tbNew = new TextBox();
                        cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
                        cellNew.Controls.Add(tbNew);

                        rowNew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((int)Session["count"] == 2)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                    {
                        TableRow rowNew = new TableRow();
                        tbl.Controls.Add(rowNew);
                        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                        {
                            TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();
                            Label lblNew = new Label();
                            lblNew.Text = "(" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + ")<br />";

                            TextBox tbNew = new TextBox();
                            cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
                            cellNew.Controls.Add(tbNew);

                            rowNew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((int)Session["count"] == 3)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                        {
                            TableRow rowNew = new TableRow();
                            tbl.Controls.Add(rowNew);
                            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                            {
                                TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();
                                Label lblNew = new Label();
                                lblNew.Text = "(" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + ")<br />";

                                TextBox tbNew = new TextBox();
                                cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
                                cellNew.Controls.Add(tbNew);

                                rowNew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.co.uk");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }//end cmdCreate_Click
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a list of if conditions, you just need to ensure the number of rows is less than your desired limit. You also should store the limit per table to avoid your count clashing if/when more tables are added.

This is how I would do it:

**(note: This won't work "as-is" - I've assumed you've removed the code to assign `tbl` within `cmdCreate_Click()`and have left it as is for clarity)**

```
namespace FormTest
{

public partial class About : Page
{

    private int myFirstTableMaxRows = 3;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        tbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Inset;
        tbl.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["myFirstTable_count"] = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            int count = (int)Session["myFirstTable_count"];
            Session["myFirstTable_count"] = ++count;
        }
    }

    protected void cmdCreate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        tbl.Controls.Clear();

        int cols = 4;
        int currentRowCount = (int)Session["myFirstTable_count"];
        if(currentRowCount <= myFirstTableMaxRows)
        {
            TableRow rowNew = new TableRow();
            tbl.Controls.Add(rowNew);
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();
                Label lblNew = new Label();
                lblNew.Text = "(" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + ")<br />";

                TextBox tbNew = new TextBox();
                cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
                cellNew.Controls.Add(tbNew);

                rowNew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://www.google.co.uk");
        }

    }//end cmdCreate_Click
}
```

**Update after question edit**

The existing rows will go due to this line in the code:

```
tbl.Controls.Clear();
```

The table is being cleared, then a single row is added per the logic in the `cmdCreate_Click()` method.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply, this has the same issue as the code I posted, I like the idea of extra sessions but it doesn't appear to be working, have you tried this code and can confirm? Gone through mine a few times but don't see what the issue is.

Comment: I've updated the question, found an issue with the rows, each time they're being generated on page load. So it never gets past one row, as it's just going past zero, creating one row each load regardless of count.